# JavaScript or css image banner navigation

Tags: javascript, css, image, banner, nav

I am trying to put an image banner navigation on my homepage using either CSS or JavaScript. I have been trying for days now with no success. Your help would be really appreciated.

I want different images to display in the banner holder depending on the link that you hover over and a default image to display if there is no hover.

I have the html and css set up for the navigation items and the images as follows:

```
<div id="banner-container">
    <img id="img1" src="./path/to/images/1.png" />
    <img id="img2" src="./path/to/images/2.png" />
    <img id="img3" src="./path/to/images/3.png" />
    <img id="img4" src="./path/to/images/4.png" />
    <img id="img5" src="./path/to/images/5.png" />
    <div id="banner-nav">  
        <ul id="navlist"> 
            <li>
                <a href="#" id="1">Portable Tracking</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" id="2">Fleet Management</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" id="3">Plug & Go</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" id="4">Trailer Tracking</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" id="5">Lone Worker</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div><!--end banner-container-->
```

Comment: Since this is not a PHP question, show your HTML, not your PHP. Also, an example on jsfiddlet.net would help.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you are asking for?

put something like this in your  tag:

```
<a href='yourlink' onMouseOver="ChangeImage(0,'ON');" onMouseOver="ChangeImage(0,'OFF');"></a>
```

and add javascript like this:

```
var img_on_src=new Array('yourimage1_on.gif','yourimage2_on.jpg','yourimage3_on.png');
var img_off_src=new Array('yourimage1.gif','yourimage2.jpg','yourimage3.png');
var img_directory = "<?php echo home_url('/'); ?>/wp-content/themes/ForetrackWP/images/";
function ChangeImage(img_id,toggle)
{
if(toggle=="ON")
document.getElementById('img' + img_id).src=img_directory + "/" + img_on_src[img_id];
else
document.getElementById('img' + img_id).src=img_directory + "/" + img_off_src[img_id];
}
```

Comment: That looks like it could do the trick, I'll give it a go. Cheers.